# Finding an invertible matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

> I want to find an invertible matrix $P$ where $P^tAP$ is a diagonal matrix.
>
> $$A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 1 \\ 2 & 0 & 2 \\ 1 & 2 & 1 \end{pmatrix} $$

I have calculated the eigenvalues of $A$: $0,-2,4$ so the diagonal of $A$ should be $$D=\begin{pmatrix} -2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 4 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} $$

How can I calculate a $P$ which verifies $D=P^tAP$?

I thought I could find $P$ doing

$$P=\begin{pmatrix} a & b & c \\ d & e & f \\ g & h&i \end{pmatrix}$$

and
multiplying $P$ and $P^t$ with $A$ but it is a long process and I am pretty sure there should be a better method to find $P$.

Comment: Find the eigenvectors and construct a matrix $P$ with them as column vectors. What does $AP$ look like in that case?

Comment: @Semiclassical The eigenvectors should be normalized.

Comment: @Dr.MV I realize that. I was leaving that detail to the OP. :) (Granted, I probably should have called it $P'$ or some such to avoid confusion.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $q(x)=x^3-2x^2-8x$, hence the spectrum is $\{-2,0,4\}$.

The nullspace of $A+2I$ is generated by $(1,-2,1)$, the nullspace of $A$ is generated by $(1,0,-1)$ and the nullspace of $A-4I$ is generated by $(1,1,1)$, hence with your $D$

$$ P = \begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}& \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ -\frac{2}{\sqrt{6}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}& 0 \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}} &\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} &-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \end{pmatrix}$$
and $P^{-1}=P^T$.

Comment: Why did you normalize the vectors? Thank you

Comment: @Jdoeoeo:in such a way $P$ is an orthogonal matrix, hence it is straightforward to get $P^{-1}$ (since it is just $P^T$).

Comment: interchanging the last two column vectors in the matrix  $P$ ; because $D$
is already set. thanks. sorry is ok

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Does this happen with all symmetrical matrix?

Comment: @Jdoeoeo: yep! - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem

Answer (score 0):

Hint :
Use characteristic equation 
$A^3 - trace(A)A^2 +(C11 +C22+C33)A - det(A)I = 0$

Cij represent Co-factor and I is identity matrix
Note : This is valid only in 3 cross 3 matrix